# Google Analytics Flash(ActionScript 2) track GETURL #anchor

Tags: javascript, flash, google-analytics, actionscript-2

I'm trying to track a #anchor for example (mysite.com/#about) the anchor is being called by Flash AS2. how can i tell GA to track hits on this page?

I tried the GETURL method in flash:

```
getURL("javascript:_gaq.push('www.dropusinit.com/#switzland');");
```

which apprently used to work, but since they've made changes this doesn't... during tests firefox navigated to a page with the url **javascript:_gaq.push('www.dropusinit.com/#switzland');** was strange.

Do I need to even use flash to ask GA to track the anchor? Is there a way i can point GA to track all anchors that are part of my page?

Answer (score 1):

It seems FireFox / Flash has an issue with this newer tracking could be the .push part of it.

How I have gotten around this, is to have another function in the HTML callGoogleAnalytics(); and call that function from the Flash. If needed you can pass the function a param as well.

HTML

```
function callGoogleAnalytics(){
   _gaq.push(['trackPageview', '/#switzland']);
}
```

Flash

```
getURL("javascript: callGoogleAnalytics();");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
getURL("javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/#switzland']);");
```

Of course the page underneath should have Google Analytcs Tracking Code already installed and using the async syntax.

Comment: tried it, still not pick up on the page hits, is there an alternative way to force GA to track anchors? i have the async code on the page below but i'm only get feedback for hits on the main page, and yes i am waiting more than 72hours before checking.